# Pass contents of file as argument to bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

In a bash script I want to do the following:

```
script.sh < some_file
```

The `some_file` is a file that has 1 single line that I want to pass it as an argument to my bash `script.sh`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 42):

Three variations:

1. Pass the contents of the file on the command line, then use that in the script.
2. Pass the filename of the file on the command line, then read from the file in the script.
3. Pass the contents of the file on standard input, then read standard input in the script.

---

Passing the contents as a command line argument:

```
$ ./script.sh "$(<some_file)"
```

Inside the script:

```
some_data=$1
```

`$1` will be the value of the first command line argument.

This would fail if you have too much data (the command that the shell would have to execute would grow too big).

---

Passing the filename:

```
$ ./script.sh some_file
```

Inside the script:

```
some_data=$(<"$1")
```

or

```
IFS= read -r some_data <"$1"
```

---

Connecting standard input to the file:

```
$ ./script.sh <some_file
```

Inside the script:

```
IFS= read -r some_data
```

The downside with this way of doing it is that the standard input of the script now is connected to `some_file`. It does however provide a lot of flexibility for the user of the script to pass the data on standard input from a file or from a pipeline.

Answer (score 12):

```
cat some_file | ./script.sh `xargs`
```

Comment: Somewhat overkill for a single line.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid worry about Bash shell quoting of the contents, use xargs to pass the whole file as-is via argument, including even a multi-line file:

```
cat input-file | xargs -0 -I XX mycommand arg1 --foo XX arg3
```

The `XX` is a placeholder I chose and could be anything as long as it doesn't appear anywhere in the command line except for where you want the `input-file` text to be placed.

`-0` tells xargs to separate the input file by the null character so that line endings are not used as separators.  This way the entire file gets passed in as a single argument (unless the file contains null characters which text files should not).

Since you have control over the script, why not pass the filename as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `read` shell-builtin you can read data from `stdin` and store the read input to shell variables:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | read a b c
$ echo $a
foo
$ echo $b
bar
$ echo $c
baz
```

As you can see, `read` splits is input into fields.  Where the input is split is determined by the `$IFS` variable (the *Input Field Seperator*).  By setting `$IFS` to the empty value, input splitting is disabled and you can save a complete line to one variable:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | IFS= read foo
$ echo $foo
foo bar baz
```